# How to bring user-added item to dropdownlist after page refresh in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, asp.net-4.5

I have a dropdownlist in my aspx page: `ddlProgramList`, which is loaded in page_load() event from Sql Server via the query: `Select Name from Programs;` The default value of this DDL is: `Select Program`

In the same page, I have a button in aspx like below, where a user can add a new Program if it does not exist in the current dropdownlist options:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPrgLabel" runat="server" style="width:295px"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnSaveProgram" runat="server" Text ="Save Program" OnClick="btnSaveProgram_Click" />
```

`btnSaveProgram_Click` function basically does an insertion to the related SQL table with the content of `txtPrgLabel`. After insertion completes, `Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);` is used to refresh the page and update the content of the DDL. This process works successfully.

What I want is: After a user adds a program, when page is refreshed, the DDL should automatically bring the recently added program instead of the default "Select Program" content. I could not find a way to manage this. Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You could store the new `Program` in a `Session` variable or any other method like query string, etc... then on `Page_Load()` you retrieve it and assign it to your dropdown.

Comment: @penleychan thanks, using session worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps to manage this demand:

1- I've defined a global variable:

```
public int maxProgramID = 0;
```

2- Found MaxID in page_load:

```
string maxID = programsDataTable.AsEnumerable()
.Max(row => row["ProgramId"])
.ToString();
```

3- Added it to my session in btnSaveProgram_Click:

```
Session["AddedProgram"] = new DDLProgram { Name = programName, Value = maxProgramID + 1 };
```

4- Select the value automatically in page_load:

```
if(Session["AddedProgram"] != null) ddl.SelectedValue = Session["AddedProgram"];
```

Thanks @penleychan to help me out by commenting under my question.